# Http post xml file to external url then receive response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post

I’m trying to make a HTTP post to an external URL and send an XML file. I’d like to do this from my MVC controller. I can see lots of advice regarding receiving XML files from a MVC controller cannot see any about sending. I would expect this is quite a simple request and would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I have created my xml file as an XDocument and would like to send to a 3rd party url using http post

I then have to receive a response from the url containing a different xml document.

1. What is the command to send the XDocument initially.
2. Do I create a new controller action with same name but [HTTPPOST] filter to receive the response?
3. Should the response parameters accept data type XDocument to receive the returned xml document?

If I’m not on the right track, please let me know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you already have an XDocument - you can call `.ToString()` which will give you a string of the XML to use as your POST request body.
2. You can use `HttpClient` to make the HTTP POST request and handle the response (see example).
3. Not sure what you mean here?

Example adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<note>\r\n  <to>Tove</to>\r\n  <from>Jani</from>\r\n  <heading>Reminder</heading>\r\n  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\r\n</note>");

string xmlRequestBody = xDocument.ToString();

// Create a New HttpClient object and dispose it when done, so the app doesn't leak resources
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
    try 
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("your_external_url", new StringContent(xmlRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")));

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // responseBody will contain the response XML document (hopefully!)
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // parse the string into an XDocument
        XDocument responseDocument = XDocument.Parse(responseBody);

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }  
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");   
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send xml content in the request body.

Pass XML string in xmlData parameter

```
    private object ProcessResponse(string xmlData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        object result = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlData))
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlData);

            using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        return result;
    }
```